# UIApplication sharedApplication Help?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm trying to access a variable that creates a navigation controller that I defined in my App Delegate in a view controller (I'm building a tab bar application with a .plist for each tab, like a drill-down app). I'm trying to get rid of the error that says "request for member "indNavControl" in something not a structure or union. Could somebody help me out?

Code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

A37dgAppDelegate *AppDelegate = (A37dgAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.indNavControl = [AppDelegate.indNavControl];

//Get the dictionary of the selected data source.
NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//Get the children of the present item.
NSArray *Children = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Children"];


if([Children count] == 0) {

    DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    A37dgAppDelegate *AppDelegate = (A37dgAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
    [AppDelegate.indNavControll push indNavControl];
    [self.indNavControl pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
    [dvController release];
}
else {

    //Prepare to tableview.
    IndustriesViewController *indViewControl = [[IndustriesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"IndustryView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    //Increment the Current View
    indViewControl.CurrentLevel += 1;

    //Set the title;
    indViewControl.CurrentTitle = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];

    //Push the new table view on the stack
    A37dgAppDelegate *AppDelegate = (A37dgAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [self.indNavControl pushViewController:indViewControl animated:YES];

    indViewControl.tableDataSource = Children;

    [indViewControl release];
}
```

}

Really, all I want to do is reference my view controller using the UIApplication sharedApplication method, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Where do you get this error? In which line?

Answer (score 0):

Did you import "A37dgAppDelegate.h" and "IndustriesViewController.h" here?

Comment: Both of them are imported, I still don't understand why it won't recognize the variables to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare 'indNavControl' in your AppDelegate as property? There should be

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSObject *indNavController;
```

or something like that in your AppDelegate.h file. Check if you have it. If not, add it.

EDIT: Also, since there is no ObjC method in

```
[AppDelegate.indNavControl];
```

you should get rid of [ and ] in this line.

EDIT2: You have multiple instances of your app delegate: at the beginning and inside 'if' statement. And their names are the same. You should delete

```
A37dgAppDelegate *AppDelegate = ...
```

inside "if" statement, because variable named "AppDelegate" already exists.

Comment: I've already got it set up as @property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigatioNController *indNavControl;

Comment: Still won't work. I'm continuing to get the same error of "Request for member 'indNavControl' in something not a structure or union"

Answer (score 0):

Which line? YOu have a typo (AppDelegate.indNavControll).

And it looks like you're using the horrible practice (yeah, I know Apple does it) of naming instance variables and properties the same, which makes things harder to read out of context. Is indNavControl a property of another class too? And an instance variable of that class too?